# How can I integrate MyCover.ai SDK on web?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sdk

I am trying to embed insurance in my application. How can I get started using the MyCover.ai SDK. I use Vue.js is there a Vue.js library that I can use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can get started with the MyCover.ai SDK by installing via npm like so:

*Javascript*: `npm install @mycoverai/mca-javascript-sdk@latest`

*Vue 3*: `npm install @mycoverai/mca-vue-sdk@latest`

*Vue 2*: `npm install @mycoverai/mca-vue-legacy-sdk@latest`

For more information on how to use the SDK checkout these links for more up to date information: [MyCover.ai SDK Docs](https://docs.mycover.ai/plugins-and-libraries/sdks/vue-3-sdk)